# Adding JavaScript variable to Django static url

Tags: javascript, django

I am attempting to add a custom Javascript variable to my Django static url. Unfortunately, the below code is failing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1)
  var text = "{% static '5LW/images/slider/" + randomNum + ".1.jpg' %}"
  document.getElementById("headerImage").style.backgroundImage = url(text)
});
```

I receive the error:

--

```
**Error during template rendering**

Could not parse the remainder: ''5LW/images/slider/"' from ''5LW/images/slider/"'

var text = "{% static '5LW/images/slider/" + randomNum + ".1.jpg %}"
```

--

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you're mixing `"` and `'` when creating your `text` variable.

However, this can never work.  The `{% static ".." %}` tag is executed by the server, and your javascript is executed (long after the server has finished processing) by the browser.

You might get this to work by using

```
var text = "{{ STATIC_URL }}/5LW/images/slider/" + randomNum + ".1.jpg";
```

(you might have to expose `settings.STATIC_URL` from your view to your template manually).

.. or perhaps:

```
var text = "{% static "5LW/images/slider/" %}" + randomNum + ".1.jpg";
```

Comment: Yes, just realised the error with the " and ', thankyou.

Comment: If this cannot work, what would be another way to achieve this?

Comment: I updated with a possible way to do it. In the olden days you could use `{{ STATIC }}` but I didn't find any references to it now...

Comment: Hi @thebjorn, I have managed to get the link working:
background-image: {% static "5LW/images/slider/6.1.jpg" %};
But I am receiving this error:
INVALID PROPERTY VALUE

Comment: sounds like you've put the `{% static ..%}` tag in a file that is not processed by the django template processor, e.g. directly in a .css file?

Comment: The static tag is going straight in the html document, as is the javascript script that creates the random number / link.

Comment: I've copied the link it creates (and fails with) and added it directly to the HTML source without the javascript / variable etc. and it works perfectly, it only stops working when I add the custom variable in the link using Javascript and then use jquery to make my custom made string the background-image url

Comment: maybe you meant `"url(" + text + ")"`?